# Salesforce Communities - Login With Salesforce

Tags: community, oauth2, single-sign-on, login-errors

Scenario:

1. I want users to log-in into community via. standard log-in options, + with Salesforce (if they have Salesforce Account) as shown below:
   [image: Example log-in page]

Now, in case i choose both the options in Login page settings as shown below, I am not being directed to home page after SSO (no clue from debug logs). The URL is simply, (you are still on login page)
**https://oneforce-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/CentralLibrary/login?inst=9**

[image: Settings here:]

However, in the settings page, if you un-select "Undefined Username and password" option, you will be directly redirected to Salesforce for login. After login you will be redirected to home page.

This is confusing to me.
1. All Community users need not to have Salesforce accounts. 
2. Community is meant for Customer and Partners, they will login via. Standard login page.
3. If partners are also using Salesforce, they might login via. their Saleforce account.

Please, let me know, why can't we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself :). 
But for others, who might struggle out there here is the clue.
After generation of session id/Token by OAuth SSO, you are not redirected to anywhere because the startURL in the CommunityLogin page is null.

Go to controller CommunitiesLoginController and give the StartURL, it will work. :)

Cheers 
ThisIsRSN